# Improbably high bitrate in the output of "iw wlan0 link"

Tags: linux, wifi, linux-networking

I am trying to determine the bitrate of a wireless connection that uses the `nl80211` driver on a Linux 2.6.39 machine. I am actually using a Netlink socket internally, but the effect is the same as calling `iw wlan0 link` and looking at the `tx bitrate` field.

I am getting intermittent results of 6227.2 MBit/s, which is clearly incorrect, as no WiFi mode could produce this speed - the channels are only a few MHz wide! I get the same from the Netlink socket and the `iw` tool.

What could be producing these spurious readings, and is there a way to suppress them, or otherwise work around?